# Positive Integers to make a square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

How many integers $n$  make the expression $7^n + 7^3 + 2\cdot7^2$ a perfect square?

Factoring $7^2$ we have that $7^n + 7^3 + 2\cdot7^2 = 7^2\cdot(7^{n-2} + 9)$.
How do we prove that the 2nd factor only has $1$ solution when $n = 3$?

Comment: So the question is: for what values of $n$ is $7^n + 7^3 + 2 \times 7^2$ a perfect square, right?

Comment: It asked how many solutions :D

Comment: This is not clear.  What does it mean to "make the expression"?

Comment: Oh sorry, I'll edit it in, it should be a perfect square,

Comment: Hint:  $7^k+3^2=m^2\implies 7^k=(m+3)(m-3)$.

Comment: there difference could only be 6 and there is only 1 solution? Thanks!

Comment: I think this question should not have the *perfect-numbers* tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An "equivalent" way of doing things, is to note that $7^3 + 2 \times 7^2 = 343+98=441 = 21^2$.

Now, if $7^n + 21^2 = y^2$ for some $y$, then $7^n = (y-21)(y+21)$.

So the prime factorization of $(y-21)$ and $(y+21)$ can both contain only the prime $7$, by unique factorization theorem. Therefore, $y - 21$ and $y+21$ are both powers of $7$. The difference between these powers of $7$ is $y+21 - (y-21) = 42$.

Only two such powers have a difference of $42$, which are $49$ and $7$.This is not very difficult to see from the fact that $7^n - 7^m = 7^{n-m}(7^{m} - 1) = 42$ forces $n-m = 1$ and $m = 1$. Therefore, $(y-21)(y+21) = 7 \times 49 = 343$, so $n = 3$ is forced from here.

---

Thinking of it, you could also have done $7^{n-2} + 9 = x^2$ since you factorized out $7^2$, but the same logic will apply, since $9 = 3^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Given $7^n+7^3+2\cdot7^2$

Note that $7^3+2\cdot7^2=441=21^2$

So, our equation becomes,
$$7^n+441=p^2\mbox{ for some integer p} $$$$7^n=p^2-441$$$$7^n=(p+21)(p-21)$$

Since $7$ is a prime number, $(p+21)$ and $(p-21)$ should be degrees of $7$

So, the only possible value of $n$ is $3$